# Response from API in PHP converted into a float number, need whole number

Tags: php, json

I am calling an external API and successfully get the result. However, one particular field that results in a numerical value is getting changed into a float number.

After the API call, this is how I am proceeding:

```
print_r($response);

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

$ids=  $responseData[0][id];
echo $ids;
```

The result I get is as follows:

```
[{"id":629378047925027252,"name":"Pizza Hut"}]
```

But for the particular `id` part the result is `6.2937804792503E+17`.

I want to retrieve the value as it is shown in the response `id` above.

Comment: Thanks for the Help AbraCadaver. It worked as explained.

Comment: Then you should accept an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_decode()` converts integers that are too big for the platform (`PHP_INT_MAX`) into floats by default.  You can have them converted into strings with `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`. See the [options parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters):

```
$responseData = json_decode($response, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

For some reason passing `null` as the third parameter doesn't force it to use the default (512) so I passed 512.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING in json_decode options parameter
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php